# ChannelFutureListener.operationComplete is not called for disconnected channel

Tags: netty

Netty 4.1.3 server.
I am using the following code to send something to client

```
final ChannelFuture future = destChannel.writeAndFlush(new BackendOutboundData( builder.build(), null));
future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
@Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
        // detect disconnected channel
        if (!future.isSuccess()) {

        }
    }
});
```

In most cases it works fine. But if the client lost the connection (No TCP closure handshake), `ChannelFutureListener.operationComplete` will not fired

**Is this an expected behavior?**

Here is my server

```
 final ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
 .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
 .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 512)
 .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
 .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
```

Comment: are you sure its not fired or is it just that the if statement is not true ?

Comment: Reason found,  the I/O thread is taken up and not freed.

Comment: You mean you block the I/O thread ? Yes you should never do this.

Comment: Yep, that is a bug and by mistake,  thanks for help